# What is this effect used by a lot of voice actors called?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, vocal

I am looking for a specific voice effect that I have listened to in many videos on YouTube and other places. I don't know what it is called and it also does not sound natural. Here are examples -

[Arpha Hub - Explainer Video](https://vimeo.com/224179742)

[Addison Anderson](https://www.voices.com/actors/adasa1329#bio)

[Ankit Arora](https://www.voices.com/actors/ankkitarorah#bio)

Do you notice the subtle 'errrrr'/crunchiness/vibration/distortion/robotic sound at the end of many words? I understand it may be difficult to understand by my explanation but hope someone recognizes it.

I would like to know if this effect has a name or something to search further into it or is there is a YouTube tutorial somewhere that I can follow, to begin with.

Any kind of pointers would help.

Comment: I think the sound you're talking about is "vocal fry'. I hate it like cancer personally, but whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an effect, it's the way these people talk. Some people have a rather raspy voice, other a smooth one. There is no effect to make your voice more raspy, unfortunately.